# How do I reference the calling dom element in a jquery ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify the class of an element if an ajax call based on that element is successful

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#a.toggle").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/changeItem.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data,text){
            if(data.error=='')
            {
                if($(this).hasClass('class1'))
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('class1');
                    $(this).addClass('class2');
                }
                else if($(this).hasClass('class2'))
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('class2');
                    $(this).addClass('class1');
                }
            }
            else(alert(data.error));
        }   
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
<a class="toggle class1" title='toggle-this'>Item</a>
```

My understanding of the problem is that in the success function *this* references the ajax object parameters, NOT the calling dom element like it does within other places of the click function.  So, how do I reference the calling dom element and check / add / remove classes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just store it in a variable. Example:

```
$("#a.toggle").click(function(e)
{
   var target = $(this);
   $.ajax({
      url: '/changeItem.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data,text)
      {
         if(data.error=='')
         {
            if(target.hasClass('class1'))
            {
               target
                  .removeClass('class1')
                  .addClass('class2');
            }
            else if(target.hasClass('class2'))
            {
               target
                  .removeClass('class2')
                  .addClass('class1');
            }
         }
         else(alert(data.error));
      }       
   });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

jQuery passes the target of the event, along with some other information about it, to your handler function. See http://docs.jquery.com/Events_%28Guide%29 for more info about this.

In your code, it'd be referenced like $(e.target).

Answer (score 3):

Better set ajax parameter : `context: this`. Example:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/changeItem.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    context: this,
    success: function(data,text){
        if(data.error=='')
        {
            if($(this).hasClass('class1'))
            {
                $(this).removeClass('class1');
                $(this).addClass('class2');
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass('class2'))
            {
                $(this).removeClass('class2');
                $(this).addClass('class1');
            }
        }
        else(alert(data.error));
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old but you can use the 'e' parameter from the click function.